# Figure out index of item in foreach

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list in my program, defined as such:
`List<String> myList = new List<String>();`

I also have a `foreach` loop, getting an item out of it:

```
foreach (String item in myList)
{
    ...
}
```

In the above loop, I want to figure out what the index of `item` is in `myList`. How can I do this?

Comment: If you are going to need the item's index, why not use a `for` loop instead of a `foreach` loop?

Comment: @GoldenDragon Now I feel like an idiot... Why didn't I think of that? It's how I'd do it in ruby and such... Thanks, man!

Comment: `List<string> n = new List<string>();
                foreach (string s in n)
                {
                  int index=  n.IndexOf(s, 0);
                }`

Comment: With a string there can be a difference.   With string IndexOf is the first match so even with {"one","two","one"}.  The last IndexOf would be 0.  Use a for or a counter.